# Concave and convex shape navigation using CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is there any way to create navigation bar with transparent background color like below image?

[image]

I tried using CSS3 pseudo selectors but the curves are not as per the design:

```
div::before{
  width: 200px;
  height: 90px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  background: radial-gradient(circle 0 at -20% 50%,transparent,transparent 100px,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100px),
   radial-gradient(circle 20px at 180px 50%,transparent,transparent 100px,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100px);
  background-size:100px 90px, 100px 90px;
  background-position:0 0,100% 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat
}
```

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: post your html too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways with CSS and I've shown few of them in the below answer. I've used `ul` and `li` tags because I feel they are more suited for a navigation bar but you can easily convert it to work with `div` tags also.

One drawback that both CSS approaches have is that the parent element is still basically a rectangle and so mouse interactions would happen outside the curve (but inside the element's boundaries). The only solution I have for this problem is to use `clip-path`.

**Using Radial Gradient:**

This is just like what you had started to do. I have just set the gradient at the correct position and have used it to produce the right hand side black border also. The curve on element's left side is done using the `border-radius` property.

The radial gradient is transparent for 20px (half the height of the element) and is black color for 1px (to produce the border), has the required background color for the rest of it.

Drawback of using gradients is that [they would not work in IE9 and lower](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) because they do not support gradients.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px; /* height - 2 * border width */
  text-indent: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(20px 20px at calc(100% + 4px) 50%, transparent 18px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 19px, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 20px, rgba(255, 255, 255, .25) 21px); /* the first color after transparent is border color, the last color is background color */
  background-clip: content-box;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, chocolate 0%, sandybrown 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Using Box Shadow:**

This has better browser support because [`box-shadow` works even in IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow). For this approach, we need a pseudo-element which is placed just inside the right border of the parent element. Both the elements (that is, the pseudo and the parent) have a `border-radius` assigned to create the curve. Background color is achieved using a wide `box-shadow` on the pseudo-element because assigning a background color to the parent or the pseudo-element will bleed outside the shape also.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 36px; /* height - 2 * border width */
  text-indent: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: calc(100% - 18px); /* 100% - (half of height  - border width) */
  top: -2px; /* inverse of border width */
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 999px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25); /* the color here is the background color */
  z-index: -1;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, chocolate 0%, sandybrown 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

You can do this using SVG also by creating the required shape with a `path` element and positioning it absolutely with respect to the parent.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
path {
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); /* border color */
  stroke-width: 2; /* border width */
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25); /* background color */
}
path:hover{
  stroke: red;
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, chocolate 0%, sandybrown 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 200 40' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
      <path d='M20,1 A19,19 0 1,0 20,39 L200,39 A19,19 0 0,1 200,1z' />
    </svg>One</li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 200 40' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
      <path d='M20,1 A19,19 0 1,0 20,39 L200,39 A19,19 0 0,1 200,1z' />
    </svg>Two</li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 200 40' preserveAspectRatio='none'>
      <path d='M20,1 A19,19 0 1,0 20,39 L200,39 A19,19 0 0,1 200,1z' />
    </svg>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What do you mean? @RakeshVadnal. The question says *navigation bar with transparent background color* and even then I've shown you a way to set background color. You just can't use the `background-color` property. For the first approach replace the `rgba(255, 255, 255, .25)` within the gradient with required bg color and for second approach replace the same in the box-shadow specified for the psuedo-element.